# 02 Ford Escape - Advice for replacing EGR valve (w/tube) with one from a junk yard?

Tags: egr, threadlocker

For some reason this sensor melted.

[image]

I had been needing to replace that tube anyways and I don't think trying to just replace that sensor would be a good idea. So I go down to the junkyard and get a new one.

I didn't separate the EGR valve from the tube because I didn't want to risk stripping the threads on my precious new tube.

I can't remember if the vacuum line was on the junkyard EGR valve so no guarantees on whether any water got in there. I think it was on but I can't remember for sure.

The junkyard tube was on there really good and the threads got a little damaged taking it off but I think they'll be fine enough.

[image]

I'm going to clean them up before putting them on my car but that'll obviously only get me so far if the threads are damaged too much.

Do you have any advice about any of this? I thought about separating the junkyard EGR valve from the tube while I have it out of the car and it's easier to work on in case the valve turns out to be bad and I have to replace it but I'm more concerned about stripping the threads at the moment and think I'll just try it as it is. As for connecting the tube to the exhaust manifold you put that on dry, correct? No thread sealer?
Thank you for any tips you provide.

Answer (score 1):

I would use your original egr.

You don’t know if the other one works - you even mention the possibility of water ingress.

Of course you can fit the egr from the scrap yard and then get to change it later when you find it does not work.